# Keep remote server synced with a Git repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm using bitbucket to host my git repos. I develop locally and push to bitbucket. I have a public testing server which I would like to keep synced with the repo. Is there a way I can use some kind of hook to tell the remove server to pull each time there is a new push? I'd rather not run a cron to pull every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This documentation](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Managing+Bitbucket+Services) discusses how to generate automatic notifications to other services when you update your bitbucket hosted repository.

It appears to include a generic `POST` service which you could use to ping your own webserver to trigger an update.

Comment: Link update: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Manage+Bitbucket+services

Comment: Both links are broken. I Believe this is the new link https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Manage+Bitbucket+hooks